# Any way to call a function automatically in Angular 6, seen ng-init doesn't work

Tags: angular, events

I want to initialize a function `setCurrentVideo()` without make any event:

```
<div *ngIf="currentVideo; else noVideo" 
     ng-init="setCurrentVideo(groups[1].filterVideos[1].stream, 'video/mp4', groups[1].filterVideos[1])">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-init` is an AngularJS directive and can't be used with Angular (starting from version 2)

If you want to call a function on component initialization with Angular, you need to use the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook into your component :

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setCurrentVideo(groups[1].filterVideos[1].stream, 'video/mp4', groups[1].filterVideos[1]);
  }

  setCurrentVideo() {
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. @Gérôme Grignon